# Tzitzit while sitting at home

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, tzitzis, summer

In the summer time, when it's hot and humid and additional clothing layers can be uncomfortable, while sitting at home is a man allowed to wear just a t-shirt or is it necessary to have the tzitzit on at all times?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12366/ http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/170/ and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29482/

Comment: @Ramin. I suspected that's where you were going with this. There are many brands of tzizit that are made of light weight summer-friendly materials. If wearing wool or poly is problematic as it should be in the heat, I suggest contacting a large Judaica store such as Eichlers or Judaica Place for a suggestion. As far as tzinut is concerned , men sometimes forget that such rules apply to them as well as women. Perhaps that is why many Hasids wear long coats in summer? However, I seriously doubt that a Modern Orthodox or even a Yeshivisha rabbi would object to a man sitting in his home in a tee..

Comment: ...as I have seen many Orthodox wear tee shirts outside, but I suspect that they would expect you to wear your tzizit too. Tzizit without a shirt? I'd guess and say that would be okay too since tzizit can be worn directly on the body. Can't a Jew go swimming in summer? Can't they walk to the pool without a shirt?

Comment: @JJLL - There's no problem with swimming during the summer, other than mixed swimming, and during 9 days (with some exceptions - separate topic.) I'm also unaware of anyone that requires that tzitzit be worn in the pool. However, as tzitzit must be worn at all times during daylight hours, one needs to wear them while walking to and from the pool. Some wear it under the shirt; others over it. This is regardless of how uncomfortable or hot it makes you feel. Besides, if you are that uncomfortable, that may be one of the reasons you're going swimming in the first place! Or sit in a walkin fridge!

Comment: @DanF. I agree with you 100%.

Answer (score -3):

Tzitzis are never required to be worn all day. However we who choose to wear them at all times have no diffrentiation between at home or outside. A kippa may or may not be a different story but as far back as the times the shulchan aruch and maharshal seems everybody was wearing them everywhere.

Comment: @user6594 - Tzitzis are never required to be worn all day - Can you cite the source for this statement? I'm unaware that there's any "casual" leniency on not wearing tzitzit at any time during the day other than perhaps, certain health reasons and swimming / bathing.

Comment: Mishna berurah siman 17 s.k. 5. Explaing the ramma there and quoting the michaber in siman 19. Meaning kulei alma modeh and les man dipalig. If you are interested in the maharshal i mentioned its in his tshuvos siman 72. Definitely worth the read specifically for the case at hand and more so as far as understanding halacha vs. societal norms. I guess i got downvoted for not providing sources?

Comment: " I guess i got downvoted for not providing sources?" - probably :-( I'll have to refer to your sources. Can you explain what your abbreviation "s.k." means?

Comment: @DanF-Siff kattan. The numbers the mishna berurah uses for interpolation of his chidushim.