# Wearing wool Tzitzis on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, sources-mekorot, clothing, tzitzis

[Is it better to wear wool tzitzis?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/152/is-it-better-to-wear-wool-tzitzis) indicates that it is better Halachically to wear a woolen Beged with woolen Tzitzis. Recently I met a fellow who the entire week wears cotton Tzitzis, yet on Shabbos wears woolen Tzitzis. He indicated that this is mentioned by Poskim (did not remember which ones), yet I have been unable to find a source. Is there a source to wear woolen Tzitzis on Shabbos, more than during the week?

Comment: As I recall it has to do with carrying. I can't source right now, though.

Comment: isn't l'kavod shabbos a good enough reason for having a nicer set of tzitzis for shabbos than for during the weekday and how how could clothing constitute carrying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yeshuas Yaakov Orach Chaim 9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41177&st=&pgnum=22&hilite=) mentions that due to the fact that a Beged made from other materials it is not clear if it is obligated in Tzitzis Biblically or Rabbinically, if it is not obligated Biblically then how can you go out into a public domain with them on Shabbos?

Comment: You mean he wouldn't let you go out if it's obligated Rabbinically? Why not?

Comment: I read his piece and frankly I'm baffled. Since when does the Torah determine what is considered a load or not? It depends on the wearer! If the wearer wants the Tzitzit there because he personally is obligated then for him they are batel to the beged and are noi not a masui! It doesn't matter that they aren't there to serve a deoraita requirement. As long as they are there because the wearer wants them there as clothing.

Comment: @Double AA Rikanti Siman 90 says that there are those that say you may not go out Friday evening with Tzitzis since Laila Lav Zeman Tzitzis, so it is a Masui! I agree that I also have a hard time understanding my answer above and thus I am unable to clarify, yet it does answer my question that there is a source for only wearing wool Tzitzis on Shabbos.

Comment: I haven't seen that inside yet, but I assume he is referring to the Teshuva of the Rif that says that. I note the Rambam argues. Either way, that doesn't explain how Rabbinic tzitzis are a masui. The Rif IIRC just says that since at night you have no need for them, then you don't really want them there and you are just carrying them around until daytime (sort of like the svara regarding the extra buttons sewn into shirts for later). Even he agrees that when you are fulfilling a mitzva you want them there so it isn't a masui.

Comment: @DoubleAA - See [here](http://divreichaim.blogspot.com/2009/06/tzitzis-on-shabbos.html) and [here](http://divreichaim.blogspot.com/2009/06/tzitzis-on-shabbos-ii.html) for some discussion of the issue. Btw, I don't think wanting them there is enough to make it not a masui. For example, let's say a beged is definitely not subject to tzitzis, but the guy thinks it is so he attaches tzitzis. The tzitzis would still be a masui on Shabbos because they are not batel to the beged.

Comment: @Fred That's because the guy only wants them there on condition that they are necessary. Let's say he thinks they look nice; would it be a masui then? (I will check the links later tonight _bli shevua_.) BTW GershonGold the relevant Rambam is Shabbat 19:20.